# Притопывать или притоптывать?

Tags: лексика

Есть мнение, что глагол "притоптывать" имеет сомнительное происхождение, неточен по значению и неправилен по образованию.

Можно ли согласиться с этим суждением и каким из глаголов пользуетесь вы?

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Удалил явно ошибочную версию, спасибо Вере.)

Можно предположить, что этот глагол связан с "топтаться", в отличие от "притопывать", близким к "топать".

Для меня естественнее звучит "притопывать", если речь о танце.

Comment: Они смеялись, посматривая сверху, дымили трубками, притоптывали на морозе (А. Толстой). И так они говорили долго, размахивали руками, притопывали, подпрыгивали... (Гайдар). Это синонимы? Есть глагол топтать - притаптывать (траву). Откуда взялся глагол "притоптывать"?

Comment: Притоптывать - то же что и притопывать (по Ефремовой).

Comment: В таком употреблении глагол "притоптывать" мог взяться напр. от непереходного глагола "топтаться" (бесцельно топтать землю). В одном случае человек изредка топает ногами, в другом - топчется. А могло и просто по созвучию мутировать.

Comment: Наверное, мутировало, что и раздражает ревнителей чистоты речи. Получился такой гибрид от "притопывать + притаптывать", при этом   значение приставок совершенно РАЗНОЕ. Вообще говоря, правильная речь заметно сдает свои позиции, языковой слух у людей ухудшается под влиянием не слишком грамотного окружения, а словарь Ефремовой излишне лоялен к таким изменениям.

Comment: _Vera: Вообще говоря, правильная речь заметно сдает свои позиции, языковой слух у людей ухудшается под влиянием не слишком грамотного окружения_ === Это Вы о Л.Н. Толстом, А.Н. Толстом, Дине Рубиной,  Захаре Прилепине и им подобных, употреблявших и употребляющих глагол "притоптывать"?